# I want to multiply two columns in different dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, spyder, multiplication

So I have a dataframe named data1 with column named 'E-E11'in it and another dataframe named Volx with a column  'EVOL' in it. I want to multiply them and it doesn't work I get a KeyError 'E-E11'.All of the columns contain 332924 values.

used this

Volx = pd.read_csv('BCCdir1VOL.csv') #already floats in dataframe
Volx.drop(Volx.columns[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]], inplace=True, axis=1) # have one column in my data frame

data1 = pd.read_csv('abaqusBCC1Dir.csv') #already floats in dataframe
data1.drop(data1.columns[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15]], inplace=True, axis=1) # have one column in my data frame

def getPower(data1, Multiplicationx, numOfCol):
for i in range(numOfCol):
Volx = 'EVOL' % (i+1)
E11x = 'E-E11' % (i+1)
Multiplicationx   = 'E11x_V' % (i+1)
data1[Multiplicationx] = data1[E11x]*Volx[Volx]
data1[Multiplicationx] = data1['E-E11']*Volx['EVOL']

instead of getting a column Multiplicationx as a new data frame of multiplying two other datat frames, I get KeyError 'E-E11'. Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda of hard to tell what's going on, but I don't understand `'EVOL' % (i+1)`.

Try:

```
Volx = f'EVOL{i+1}'
E11x = f'E-E11{i+1}'
Multiplicationx = f'E11x_V{i+1}'
data1[Multiplicationx] = data1[E11x] * Volx
```

Comment: Didn't get the new dataframe Multiplicationx, but still got this error: KeyError: 'E-E11'